# How to convert a part of the webpage as an image?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have this link of a structure of a chemical compound (http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/image/imgsrv.fcgi?cid=4684&t=l) which I want to convert into a .jpg file. Imgur doesn't accept this link directly probably because it doesn't end in .jpg or .png etc. in my mobile version.

I can't save anything locally. An online way of doing this is what I need. A solution based solely on the browser.

How can I possibly do this conversion?

Comment: Since you're not really asking about a specific web app, but rather how to do something with the browser and no local file access, this is probably off-topic here and would be a better question for [su].

Comment: Can you add browser extensions? For instance, the [Google Drive extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-drive/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf)? It, at least, has a way to convert an entire web page into a PDF and save it to your Google Drive. I expect there are other extensions/add-ons out there that can do similar.

Comment: @AlE. But that extension needs to be saved locally first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you open that link in your web browser (for example Google Chrome), and right click on the image, you can choose 'Save image as...'. Choose a filename for the image. You can then freely upload the saved file to a tool like imgur to do the JPG conversion, or perform it yourself easily with Microsoft Paint or GIMP.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for this. I forgot to mention that I can't save anyhting locally. Only online way of doing this is what I needed.

Comment: Are you able to plug in an external USB/thumb drive, and save there?

Comment: I was able to successfully upload the image from the link you specified at imgur.com: http://imgur.com/9bkaPm4

Comment: Nope. Only the browser access.

Comment: Bravo. Please share it with me :)

Comment: Umm......how did you do it?